# find / -iregex ".*large_files.*" ran endless

Tags: bash, find

I run the command to find the files named `".*large_files.*"`

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# find / -iregex ".*large_files.*"
/root/search_large_files.py
```

It found the file but the cursor is shinning endless even if I leave it alone for over half an hour.

What's the bug in my codes to cause the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it *may* be that you just have massive file systems :-)

But, if you think it shouldn't be taking that long, you may well have mount points that are slower than normal, such as NFS-mounts where you have to go out over the network to get file information.

You could probably see a slow-down in that case if you just run `find /` on its own. If it goes out to an external location (like, I don't know, a ZX80 running in Antartica), the output rate may show that, and you'll be able to identify where in the hierarchical structure it happens.

Another possibility is to restrict it to the actual file system you're on to minimise the chance it will go external. That would be by using the `xdev` flag to prevent it crossing file systems. On my VM with one root file system but mounts for my C and D host drives, I cut the time down from two minutes to seventeen seconds.

Of course, that won't go to *other* local file systems but you could, if necessary write a script to find (with `xdev`) the file on all file systems marked `ext4` (and whatever other ones you deem to be local).